# Can we use a REST api as a data source for Siddhi Event tables?

Tags: siddhi

My use case - I want to use stored data in my Siddhi queries.

To this end, I'm looking at using the Siddhi table concept to provide an abstraction for my stored data.

However, my stored data is available via a REST api. I understand that you can plug in external databases as sources for Siddhi tables, is there a provision to plug in a REST api as a data source as well ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [http-request sink](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-io-http/api/1.0.43/#http-request-sink) and [http-response](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-io-http/api/1.0.43/#http-response-source) source to call your REST endpoint and get required data. [This](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/siddhi-io-http/blob/master/component/src/test/java/org/wso2/extension/siddhi/io/http/sink/HttpRequestResponseTestCase.java#L54) is an example.

Comment: Hi Tishan, thanks for your response. My use case is this - I have a stream A that I want to run Siddhi queries against.  I also have a static source of data that I want to be able to use in my Siddhi queries together with stream A. The data being static cannot be streamed. I was thinking that I would use a Siddhi table to represent this static data source.  However, the static data source is available to me via a REST api, so is it possible for me to pull data from the REST api into a Siddhi table ?